# Control transparency of an image with touch on Android(Steam effect)

Tags: android, image, touch, transparency, swipe

I would want to make an image transparent (like steam on an Image) and then remove the transparent effect when user swipes on the screen.
Its like removing the effect only at those places where user swipes on the screen.

I Have Attached Images to make it more clear. How to control the touch and do operation on that part of the image.
Any help would be appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think you have to overlay 2 images: one with the picture and one with the "steam". Then remove (cut out) some steam on touch (which is nothing more than dawing some lines using a round cap limiter for the line endings)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I was thinking on the lines to make the image transparent and the decrease the transparency on touch.Which I was unsure on how to do that on touch.
But your approach seems fine if i want steam like appearance.Could you elaborate more on how to cut out the steam part on touch.

Comment: Here is how to use the PorterDuff masking to cut holes http://www.techrepublic.com/article/punch-a-hole-in-a-bitmap-by-using-androids-porter-duff-xfer/. For drawing, check out the **FingerPaint** sample app in your SDK. Combine the two and get your effect.

Comment: Glad to have pointed you in the right direction!